# How to loop through variables?

Tags: powershell

I have a several scripts that are using PowerCLI to pull info from all of our virtual center servers and dumping into an HMTL file. At this time I have one script setup for each virtual center server, howerver I want to modify it so that I have one main script that will loop through each virtual center and create a HTML for each one instead of having to maintain several different scripts. I have tried declaring each VC as a variable, for example:

$vc = "vc1" , "vc2"

however that only generated one HTML file using the last variable. What would be the best way to accomplish this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! You need to include way more detail.

Comment: Is the script the same for each VC server?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
"Server01","Server02" | ForEach-Object {
  Connect-VIServer -Server $_ -User user -Password password;
}
```

Also add the rest of the code that you need to apply to each Server with in the ForEach-Object's { }. You can then name each HTML file with the `$_` (server name inside the loop) variable as well.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` is what you want I think